# Cannot use PuTTy for openSUSE Yast 2 due to corrupt coloring

Tags: putty, opensuse

Thats how my yast looks in putty: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9wDe.png

Anyone any ideas how can I fix this? I already did export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1 to get lines instead of characters as line in yast. Changing colors does not help because the colors set (default) doesn't change when going into yast ... I'm using default settings in PuTTy

## Solution:

Well, I just saw putty is doing entries in registry, so I just remove the complete PuTTy key. After that, I restarted putty, and the color problem was fixed already ... I can't remember that I ever should have changed anything here .. anyway, complete reinstallation worked for me tho. I found another method to fix the line problem: PuTTy - Connection - Data and change xterm in terminal-data string to unix. Worked for me.

Source (Ger): http://www.mediamill.de/blog/2008/03/25/darstellung-von-umlauten-und-linien-bei-einer-ssh-verbindung-mit-putty-zu-einer-opensuse-101-installation/

Comment: What about  - http://superuser.com/questions/219231/how-to-set-default-screen-colours-in-putty-ssh does that work for you?

Comment: For me this link only describes how to save color settings for all and permanently. I never changed them so I'm using defaults on all. My normal coloring is fine, just in yast I cannot read anything.